# Maximization of N modulo k when N is fixed, and k<=N

Tags: algorithm, optimization, modular-arithmetic

> Suppose there are **N** collectibles. You can call a minimum of 1 person to a maximum of **k** persons to collect those collectibles for you. The number of people you call would share a number of collectibles equally among them in the *highest equity* possible for the value of **N**. You get the remaining collectibles that are left over. *Optimize* the number of people called so that you can get the maximum possible no. of collectibles, and output that **maximum possible number of collectibles** which you could get. For example, if there were 11 collectibles, and you could call a maximum of 3 persons, then you could get 2 collectibles at most. This is because if you'd call 3 persons, they'd distribute the collectibles in the highest equity possible out of 11, that is 3. So you'd be left with 2 collectibles.

An obvious way of approaching the problem is to set up a loop running until **k**, and storing the maximum possible **N modulo k**. But this being a blunt approach, I want to make the code more efficient by *maximizing* **N modulo k** under the constraints that **N is fixed** and **k<=N**. Can someone provide me with a possible approach to optimize the above problem?

**PS**: I've not included any code, as the blunt approach is quite obvious, and I'm seeking for an approach for the way I desire to proceed through the problem, and not the **code**.

Comment: If you already have a working code and are looking for optimization, you should post to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This site is for helping understanding  a non-working program or behavior.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcq I would say he's rather asking for suggestions regarding which algorithm he might use to solve this problem. The fact that he knows how to write a brute-force solution isn't really relevant, it just satisfies the SO requirement that he's done some thinking before asking the question, so I don't think the question is out of place here. On the other hand, CS or MATH stackexchange might be more suitable.

Comment: @Berthur fair enough, I wasn't sure which one to suggest. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MattTimmermans `k` passed to the function can be less than `N / 2 + 1`. See the example in the question: for `N = 11` and `k = 3`, the result is `max(11 % 1, 11 % 2, 11 % 3) == 2` What OP wants is an algorithm to implement `def maximizeModulo(N: int, k: int)`, that works faster than `O(k)`.

Comment: This seems challenging to solve quickly for a single N, but in O(M log k) time (for example, haven't thought deeply about this) you could find the answer for every N in 1..M.